# Inconsistent behavior of WhenEvent[ ]

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, event-detection

Consider the following simple example:

```
sol = NDSolve[ {x''[t] == 1, x'[0] == 0, x[0] == 0,
               WhenEvent[Abs[x[t]] > 1 && x[t] > 2, {x'[t] -> -3 x'[t]}]}, 
               x[t], {t, 0, 4}];
Plot[x[t] /. sol[[1]], {t, 0, 4}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Clearly `WhenEvent[]` is missing the `x[t] > 2` occurrence. This *may* happens (my interpretation) if the event detection routine checks for the occurrence of the first part of the AND clause and *then* for the other AND components, instead of checking them as an OR event trigger. 
As the `Abs[x[t]] > 1` event isn't fired again between 1 and 2, the rest of the AND clause doesn't get tested again.

In testing this interpretation, we can reverse the clause:

```
sol = NDSolve[{x''[t] == 1, x'[0] == 0, x[0] == 0,
              WhenEvent[x[t] > 2 && Abs[x[t]] > 1, {x'[t] -> -3 x'[t]}]}, 
               x[t], {t, 0, 4}];
Plot[x[t] /. sol[[1]], {t, 0, 4}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

which now works as expected. Of course this isn't a proof.

But the strange thing is that reverting to the first version, but encapsulating the clause in a function, also works as expected:

```
clause[p_] := Abs[p] > 1 && p > 2
sol = NDSolve[{x''[t] == 1, x'[0] == 0, x[0] == 0,
              WhenEvent[clause[x[t]], {x'[t] -> -3 x'[t]}]}, x[t], {t, 0, 4}];
Plot[x[t] /. sol[[1]], {t, 0, 4}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

So, what is the moral? Always put your `WhenEvent[]` clause as a function?

Comment: Even weirder: try `WhenEvent[Null;Abs[x[t]]>1&&x[t]>2,{x'[t]->-3x'[t]}]`..

Comment: @Silvia That's crazy. Perhaps the `WhenEvent[ ]` thing isn't mature enough

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From [`WhenEvent`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/WhenEvent.html):

> Examples of events and how $t_a$ is determined include:
> ...
> `f == 0 && pred` --   `f` crosses zero and `pred` is `True`

I believe that the same special case is applied to `And` for forms `f > 0 && pred`, etc.

So

```
WhenEvent[Abs[x[t]] > 1 && x[t] > 2, {x'[t] -> -3 x'[t]}]
```

means the event will be triggered when `Abs[x[t]]` crosses `1` *and* `x[t] > 2`, which is never.

Next,

```
 WhenEvent[x[t] > 2 && Abs[x[t]] > 1, {x'[t] -> -3 x'[t]}]
```

means the event will be triggered when `x[t]` crosses `2` *and* `Abs[x[t]] > 1`, which will be whenever `x[t]` crosses `2`.

Finally, both

```
WhenEvent[clause[x[t]], {x'[t] -> -3 x'[t]}]
WhenEvent[Null; Abs[x[t]] > 1 && x[t] > 2, {x'[t] -> -3x'[t]}]
```

do not have the head `And`, so the special case is not applied; they will trigger an event whenever they change from `False` to `True`.

Comment: I've read the docs, but I understood them as a simple application of logic. Your interpretation (probably correct) seems _dangerous_ because you have to be sure to cover all the possible timelines with OR clauses ... or just encapsulate the whole thing as a function which is probably worse from the performance POV

Comment: @belisarius It could be that only crossings, such as `f == 0`, were meant to be special-cased, and you've found a bug.  Clearly `f == 0` has to be a special case, and one would want to allow conditions to be placed on which crossings trigger events.  But `&&` here seems to behave logically like "when", and that's unintuitive.

Comment: With `Equal[ ]` there are not ambiguities. It will trigger the event when it's true, so everything is OK. But in the case of inequalities (or other conditions) the "condition true" zone wont (in general) coincide with the rest of the testing. So yes, it is _at least_ confusing.

Comment: @belisarius Practically speaking, the `Equal` statements are never true.  The solver looks for a change in sign (or a crossing).  Try it with `clause[p_] := p == 2 && Abs[p] > 1`.

Comment: There is a saying in Spanish. I don't really know if it makes sense in English _"Among firefighters we will not step on the hose."_

Comment: @belisarius I get it, but I doubt I'll be repeating it. :)

Comment: Oh! It doesn't have _that_ meaning in Spanish :)

Comment: @belisarius I didn't mean *that* either.  I just meant I don't think my friends will understand it. :)

Comment: Thank you. This `WhenEvent` issue bothers me all the time. However, why is `WhenEvent` designed in this way? The logic behind it is clear but very counterintuitive to me.

Comment: I dont't think wheather the `Head` is `And` maters. Check this: `Reap[NDSolve[{y'[x] == y[x] Cos[x + y[x]], y[0] == 1, WhenEvent[(Null; (y[x] < 0.3) && (y'[x] == 0)), Sow[{x, y[x]}]]}, y, {x, 0, 30}]]` This can only work if reverse the order.

Comment: @luyuwuli I'm unclear what your example is meant to show and what you mean by the reverse order. The head of the expression `(Null; (y'[x] == 0) && (y[x] < 0.3))` is `CompoundExpression`, so `WhenEvent` processes the code as a simple logical statement and looks for it to change truth value at consecutive sample points. But the logical expression itself is `False` at all sample points. (It's highly unlikely for `y'[x] == 0` to be `True` with floating point numbers.) So no events, which is what the output shows. The same happens if the order of the arguments in the `And` statement is reversed.

Comment: @luyuwuli Why is it designed this way: First, in an approximate solver, an equation `f[x] == 0` is almost never satisfied. So we certainly do not want `f[x] == 0 && pred` treated strictly logically. Second, we sometimes want to specify the direction of crossing (e.g., pos -> neg), and Wolfram chose to use `<` and `>`. The old `"EventLocator"` method had a `"Direction"` option, but WRI chose to discard that. They might have chosen a syntax like `WhenEvent[{event, pred}, action]` with `List` instead of `And`, but they didn't. Basically their choices reduce typing at some expense of clarity.

Comment: @MichaelE2 I run my code again; it doesn't behave as I said in the comment; I probably messed up the code at that time, sorry about this. Do you mean by changing the head, _Mathematica_ will treat p1 and p2 equally in the `WhenEvent[p1&&p2,...]` ? BTW, I prefer the syntax you said in your comment, which is more clear.

Comment: @luyuwuli "Do you mean by changing the head, Mathematica will treat `p1` and `p2` equally in the `WhenEvent[p1&&p2,...]`?"  Yes, and it won't do any special processing of equations or inequalities.  It strictly looks for a change from `False` to `True`.  Compare with `WhenEvent[p1 && p2 == True,...]` (head is `Equal`) for `y'[x] == 0 && y[x] < 0.3` in your ODE.  BTW, I like my syntax, too.  It seems consistent with optimization functions, e.g. `{fn, constraints}`, too.  Maybe they will add that syntax someday.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Now I get it. Thank you very much:)