# How to use WhenEvent with several conditions?

Tags: differential-equations

I would like to use `StopIntegration` in `WhenEvent`, when more than one condition should be checked. For example, in the code below I would like to integrate until either `q1[t] == 0` or `q2[t] == 0`

```
sol[s_] := 
 NDSolve[{q1'[t] == -q2[t], q2'[t] == q1[t], q1[0] == Cos[s], 
   q2[0] == Sin[s], 
   WhenEvent[
    q1[t] == 0 || q2[t] == 0, {tmax = t, "StopIntegration"}]}, {q1, 
   q2}, {t, 0, 10}]
```

But it does not work, when I try to check it

```
Manipulate[
 ParametricPlot[
  Evaluate[{q1[t], q2[t]} /. sol[s], {t, 0, tmax}, 
  PlotRange -> 1], {{s, Pi/4}, 0, 2 Pi}]
```

although it works perfectly if I leave only one of the conditions. Of course in this simple example I can just write `q1[t]q2[t]==0`, but I would like to understand how to proceed in general with more complex conditions.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I think you should specify a *list* of events: `WhenEvent[{q1[t] == 0, q2[t] == 0}, {youractions}]` . Take a look at the "Scope" section of the WhenEvent docs, under "Events", for a similar example.

Comment: Thanks, it works. But it still a little bit strange for me. For example, `q2[t] == 0 && q1[t] > 0` works, but `q1[t] > 0 && q2[t] == 0` does not.

Comment: I agree! So far I only managed to make one condition per `WhenEvent` expression work at a time. It would stand to reason that it should accept compound conditions, but either it just doesn't, or I have not found a way to coax it to do it yet...

Comment: Note that things like `f == 0` and `f == 0 && pred`, also with `<`, `>`, and `Mod`, are special cases in `WhenEvent` (see http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/39374/inconsistent-behavior-of-whenevent/39393#39393), compared to the general `pred`, where the "event" is `pred` changing from `False` to `True`.