# Options of WhenEvent

Tags: differential-equations, event-detection, discontinuity

I'm using NDSolve and WhenEvent to simulate building heating systems and their discontinuous operation. Here is a simplified example.

The idea is quite simple. I have the following WhenEvents:

```
{WhenEvent[True && (tt[tau] <= 19) && (ta[tau] < 10), Q[tau] -> 10000],
WhenEvent[{tt[tau] >= 21, ta[tau] >= 10}, Q[tau] -> 0]}
```

I understand that there are some problems with WhenEvents if I use And as Head in the conditions. I found out that adding a True improves its behaviour.

The actual problem requires a large equation system. I don't want any event missed, because it causes singularity problems. According to the documentation, I should use

```
"IntegrateEvent" -> True, "DetectionMethod" -> "Interpolation"
```

Applying these into the differential equations

```
Cwirk = 50 25 3;
ta[tau_] := 10 - 10 Cos[Pi/(12) tau]
sol = Flatten[
       NDSolve[{Q[tau] - 200 (tt[tau] - ta[tau]) == Cwirk tt'[tau],

         WhenEvent[True && (tt[tau] <= 19) && (ta[tau] < 10), 
              Q[tau] -> 10000, "IntegrateEvent" -> True, 
              "DetectionMethod" -> "Interpolation"],

         WhenEvent[{tt[tau] >= 21, ta[tau] >= 10}, Q[tau] -> 0, 
          "IntegrateEvent" -> True, "DetectionMethod" -> "Interpolation"],

          tt[0] == 10, Q[0] == 10000}, {tt, Q}, {tau, 0, 24 7}, 
        DiscreteVariables -> Q]]
```

It gives the following errors

```
NDSolve::nlnum1: The function value {-11.,True} is not a list of numbers with dimensions {2} when the arguments are {0.,10.,10000.}.
Join::heads: Heads List and Experimental`NumericalFunction[{Hold[Function[{tau,tt,Q},{-21+tt,tt<=19&&Plus[<<2>>]<10}]],Apply},{0,{<<1>>}},<<2>>,{<<1>>},{Function[{NDSolve`Monitor$3956},Function[{NDSolve`Monitor$3956$3957,NDSolve`Monitor$3956$3958,NDSolve`Monitor$3956$3959},Internal`InheritedBlock[{Q,tau,tt},<<1>>]]],None,None}] at positions 1 and 2 are expected to be the same.
NDSolve::nlnum1: The function value {-11.,True} is not a list of numbers with dimensions {2} when the arguments are {0.,10.,10000.}.
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Relevant (perhaps obscurely): https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/39393/4999

Comment: What about `WhenEvent[{tt[tau] <= 19, ta[tau] < 10}, Q[tau] -> 10000]` for the first event?

Comment: @MichaelE2 Change of the events order doesn't help. I think the problem is the options. If I remove the options, it works despite of errors.

Comment: I'm not following: I didn't change the order (2nd comment). -- I think the problem is the `True`, which only shows up as a problem in the code that is invoked when the options are used. -- This is perhaps a better representation of what I think you're after: `WhenEvent[{(tt[tau] <= 19) && (ta[tau] < 10), ta[tau] < 10 && tt[tau] <= 19}, Q[tau] -> 10000]`, with or without the options.

Comment: Oh it works! It seems that True really causes the problem. I've tried WhenEvent[Null; (tt[tau] <= 19) && (ta[tau] < 10), Q[tau] -> 10000]. It gives the same error. Seems like WhenEvent is not that stable.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### Events are processed in special ways

Consider the general form:

```
WhenEvent[ A && B , code; actions, options...]
          ^event ^
```

Though the title suggests options are a key interest in the OP, they are not the main problem underlying the error.  One may put `code` before the actions, which are rules or keyword strings.  I use it below, but it, too, is irrelevant to the problem.

I wish to focus on the `event` argument `A && B`.  When the `event` has the head `And`, it is a special case that is treated in the following way, which leads many to misunderstand `WhenEvent`:

> **As an event in `WhenEvent[]`, `A && B` is not logically equivalent to "A AND B"; rather, it is equivalent to "A IF B."**

There are several special forms outlined in the docs for the principal part of the event `A` that get translated into appropriate event conditions. Expressions `A` that do not match the forms are treated as is and their T/F values are tracked.  The gist of the docs is that an event is triggered when the value of `A` changes from `False` to `True`, *provided* the predicate `B` is `True` at the time.

An example of a special form is when `A` has the head `Equal`, such as `f == 0`.  The equation `f == 0` is virtually never `True` in a discrete, numerical solver, unless by some chance a numerical step lands `f` exactly equal to zero.  So instead it is treated as equivalent to two events `f > 0` and `f < 0`.  A similar case is `g == c`, which is translated to the `f == 0` case via `f = g - c`. The form `Mod[..] == 0` is another special case.  We'll come back to some of the special forms below, ones that seem related to the problem at hand.

### A workaround for some cases

When "A AND B" is desired, one way is to hide the `And` in another function:

```
event[t_] := A && B; (* presumably A, B are expressions in terms of t *)
NDSolve[... WhenEvent[event[t], ...]...]
```

Now the head is `event` and not `And`. Further, `event[t]` is not evaluated symbolically to see if it results in a `And[..]` expression.  In this case an event will be triggered when `event[t]` changes from `False` to `True`.  This method can be used for other complicated logical combinations of conditions. (Beware: `event[t]` should not contain equalities, because they are virtually never `True` as discussed above.)

*Alternatives or not:*

One might try to come up with alternatives, especially you like to avoid defining unnecessary functions like `event[]`.  Sometimes the obvious works and sometimes not:

```
If[A && B, True, False]  (* works *)
(A && B) == True         (* fails *)
```

I thought `(A && B) == True` was a clever way to hide the head `And`, but as noted above, the head `Equal` is another special case.  This condition is transformed to

```
(A && B) - True == 0
```

(via the `f = g - c` transformation mentioned above).  Internally a condition `f == 0` is represented by a function that must have numerical values, which are used to detect a zero crossing.  Obviously `(A && B) - True` is not numerical, and you get a `NDSolve::nrnum1` error like the OP.

### Example of various forms

To see how `A && B` compares with `event[t]` in all logical combinations, I'll use for `A && B` the following condition:

```
Sin[3 t] > 0 && Cos[t] > 0
```

The following will increment the discrete variable `p` at each `A && B` event, the variable `q` at each `event[t]` event, and as well, the variable `r` whenever `A` or `B` separately change from `False` to `True`.

```
Clear[event, p, q, r, x, t];
event[t_] := Sin[3 t] > 0 && Cos[t] > 0;
ss = NDSolve[{p[1] == 0, q[1] == 0, r[1] == 0,
    WhenEvent[Sin[3 t] > 0 && Cos[t] > 0, p[t] -> p[t] + 0.1],
    WhenEvent[event[t], q[t] -> q[t] + 0.1],
    WhenEvent[{Sin[3 t] > 0, Cos[t] > 0}, r[t] -> r[t] + 0.1],
    x'[t] == 1, x[1] == 1},
   {p, q, r}, {t, 1, 20},
   DiscreteVariables -> {p, q, r}, MaxStepSize -> 0.5];
Show[
 RegionPlot[{Sin[3 t] > 0, Cos[t] > 0}, {t, 1, 20}, {y, -1, 1.2}, 
  BoundaryStyle -> Thin], 
 Plot[{Sin[3 t], Cos[t], p[t] /. ss, q[t] /. ss, r[t] /. ss},
  {t, 1, 20}, PlotLegends -> {None, None, p, q, r}],
 AspectRatio -> 0.6
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The shading from `RegionPlot` shows when `A` is true (blue) and `B` is true (golden).

### A solution for the OP

```
Cwirk = 50 25 3;
ta[tau_] := 10 - 10 Cos[Pi/(12) tau];
evts = {};  (* optional: linked list for recording events; see plot *)
sol = Flatten[
   NDSolve[{Q[tau] - 200 (tt[tau] - ta[tau]) == Cwirk tt'[tau], 
     WhenEvent[{tt[tau] <= 19 && ta[tau] < 10, 
       ta[tau] < 10 && tt[tau] <= 19},
      evts = {evts, on[tau]}; Q[tau] -> 10000,
      "IntegrateEvent" -> True, "DetectionMethod" -> "Interpolation"],
      WhenEvent[{tt[tau] >= 21, ta[tau] >= 10},
      evts = {evts, off[tau]}; Q[tau] -> 0,
      "IntegrateEvent" -> True, "DetectionMethod" -> "Interpolation"],
      tt[0] == 10, Q[0] == 10000}, {tt, Q}, {tau, 0, 24 7}, 
    DiscreteVariables -> Q]];
evts = Flatten@evts;
Show[
 Plot[{tt[tau] /. sol, Q[tau]/1000 /. sol, ta[tau]}, {tau, 0, 24 7}, 
  PlotStyle -> {Automatic, Purple, Gray}, PlotPoints -> 500, 
  PlotLegends -> {tt, Q, ta}],
 Prolog -> {AbsoluteThickness[0.6],
   Red, InfiniteLine[{#, 0}, {0, 1}] & /@ Cases[evts, on[t_] :> t],
   Black, InfiniteLine[{#, 0}, {0, 1}] & /@ Cases[evts, off[t_] :> t]},
 PlotRange -> All, Frame -> True, AspectRatio -> 1/3, 
 AxesOrigin -> {0, 10}
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

(The red grid lines are events when the heat was turned on, and the black are when the heat was turned off.)

### On the OP's problems and `WhenEvent` options

I have a guess, which could be interpreted as supported by the documentation, as to why the options lead to error message.  From the tutorial [Events and Discontinuities in Differential Equations](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolveWhenEvents.html), the description of the `"DetectionMethod"` option value is:

> "Interpolation" -- interpolate the event function with a polynomial with the same order as the method.

I interpret (or guess) this means that the event needs to be defined by a numeric function derived from the condition `A`.  When `A` is of the form `f == 0`, `f > 0`, etc., the expression `f` is used.  When `A && B` is of the form `True && ...`, then `A` is `True` and this expression is used.  Unfortunately `True` is not a numeric function and `"DetectionMethod" -> "Interpolation"` fails to work.  Neither the error message nor the documentation clearly says this is not allowed, although I'm suggesting it can be inferred from the snippet above.  In any case, it seems to me to be the case, which I will summarize in the following rule:

> **The option `"DetectionMethod" -> "Interpolation"` may be used in `WhenEvent` only when the event is defined by a numeric function (such as `f == 0`, `f > 0`, or `f < 0`).**

(Side note: In the tutorial, it indicates `"DetectionMethod" -> "Interpolation"` automatically invokes `"IntegrateEvent" -> True`. So it is unnecessary to use both as above and in the OP.)

Comment: Wow! Thank you for your extremely detailed explanation and example!

Comment: Things seem to be more complicated than summarized, `event2[t_] := Sin[3 t] > 0;WhenEvent[event2[t] && Cos[t] > 0, p[t] -> p[t] + 0.1]` give same result as `q`. I even begin wondering if these behaviors are bugs…