# WhenEvent fails in NDSolve

Tags: differential-equations, event-detection

The code with one condition `Mod[t, 2 π] == 0`

```
data = Block[{d = 0.15, r = 0.3}, 
  Reap[NDSolve[{x''[t] + d x'[t] - x[t] + x[t]^3 == r Cos[ t], 
     x[0] == 0, x'[0] == 0, 
     WhenEvent[Mod[t, 2 π] == 0(*&&t>50*), 
      Sow[{t, x[t], x'[t]}]]}, {}, {t, 0, 100}, 
    MaxSteps -> ∞]]]
```

works well in v11.3, and gives the data as below

```
{{{}}, {{{6.28319, 0.895631, 
    0.418075}, {12.5664, -1.21673, -0.312119}, {18.8496, -0.405354, 
    0.587376}, {25.1327, -0.254392, -0.19556}, {31.4159, -0.40937, 
    0.151545}, {37.6991, -0.141298, 0.702613}, {43.9823, -1.09087, 
    1.0678}, {50.2655, -0.921924, -0.607913}, {56.5487, -0.594581, 
    0.48939}, {62.8319, 1.09998, -0.105309}, {69.115, 1.19792, 
    0.541834}, {75.3982, -1.09163, -0.417725}, {81.6814, -0.479742, 
    0.483879}, {87.9646, 0.846189, 
    0.400168}, {94.2478, -1.28112, -0.186879}}}}
```

However, when conditions `Mod[t, 2 π] == 0&&t>50` are applied, the data for `t>50` is not outputed. 
Somebody can explain it? Any suggestions would be much appreciated!

Comment: Perhaps  [Options of WhenEvent](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/154539/options-of-whenevent) might help.

Comment: By the way your code doesn't work well...

Comment: @UlrichNeumann OP's code works as illustrated in _v11.3_.

Comment: @xzczd You're right, I tried it with an event-function `event[t_] := Mod[t, 2 \[Pi]] == 0` :  MMA v12 evaluates `{{{}}, {}}` in this case.

Comment: @UlrichNeumann This can be explained in a manner similar to my answer below. Since `WhenEvent` has the attribute `HoldAll`, when this intermediate function is introduced, `WhenEvent` only _sees_ a `event[t]`, so, as mentioned in the **Details and Options** section of `WhenEvent`, it uses the strategy for _pred_  to detect the event i.e. the event is detected only if the predicate _pred_ becomes `True`, which is almost impossible, while when one directly write `Mod[t, 2 Pi] == 0` or use `event[t]//Evaluate` to make it explicit, `WhenEvent` will _see_ it and turn to the specialized strategy.

Comment: @xzczd Thanks for your profound explanation! That means the solutions found in [Options of WhenEvent](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/154539/options-of-whenevent) aren't valid anymore?

Comment: @UlrichNeumann The explanation therein is consistent with mine, if I've understood it correctly. As mentioned there: "The gist of the docs is that an event is triggered when the value of `A` changes from `False` to `True`…… The form `Mod[..] == 0` is another special case " But the emphasis is a little different, and we just can't use the solution there mechanically.

Comment: @xzczd In v12 it seems to be necessary to use `event[t]//Evaluate`, in the link `event[t]` was sufficient.

Comment: @UlrichNeumann I think this is the specialness of `Mod[…] == 0`, which is not discussed in detail in that answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'm not sure how to explain this behavior, but I've found a solution. Just move the condition to 2nd argument of `WhenEvent`:

```
WhenEvent[Mod[t, 2 π] == 0, If[t > 50, Sow@{t, x[t], x'[t]}]]
```

Comment: Thanks for your explanation of the Detail in the docs, and it really works!

Comment: @keanhy14 I've removed the explanation part, because it seems to be incorrect, at least incomplete. Consider the following: `WhenEvent[Mod[t, 2 \[Pi]] == 0 && Mod[t, 2 \[Pi]] == 0, Sow[{t, x[t], x'[t]}]]`. The underlying issue is more intricate than I thought. You may have a look at the [linked answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/154560/1871) together with my comment there.

Comment: Consider the example beginning "Use an event y(t)==0  with the condition x(t)>0" under Scope/Events in the `WhenEvent` documentation, which looks somewhat like the usage in the question.  It works fine.  However, if `y[t] = 0` is replaced by `Mod[t, 2]`, it does not work.  Referring to the Details and Options section of the documentation, even though "f == 0 && pred" is an acceptable event, evidently "Mod[t, \[CapitalDelta]t] == 0 && pred" is not.

Comment: @bbgodfrey Yeah, the behavior of 3 types of condition (`f==0 || f>0 || f<0`, `Mod[…]==0`, `pred` that doesn't belong to the former two) is really confusing inside `And`: `Mod[…]==0` seems never work; `f == 0 && pred` or  `f == 0 && g > 0` seems to be triggered when `f == 0` changes from `False` to `True`, and `pred`  or `g>0` is `True`; `pred1 && pred2` is triggered when either of the conditions changes from `False` to `True`, and the other one is `True`; there may be more. If  `WhenEvent` is designed to behave like this, then it's really a bad design.

Comment: You have thought about this more than I have.  Do you plan to report it to Wolfram, Inc.?

Comment: @bbgodfrey I haven't thought out a good way to summarize these, or perhaps I should file every example as a separate report? Something funnier: `WhenEvent[Mod[t, 2 \[Pi]] == 0 && t > (2 Pi - 10^-6) // Evaluate, Sow[t]]` works, but `WhenEvent[Mod[t, 2 \[Pi]] == 0 && t > (2 Pi - 10^-6), Sow[t]]` doesn't work.

Comment: Perhaps, `Evaluate` turns `Mod[t, 2 \[Pi]] == 0 && t > (2 Pi - 10^-6)` into a single `pred` in the eyes of `WhenEvent`.

Comment: @bbgodfrey This seems to be related to the `FullForm` of `2 Pi - 10^-6`, `With[{number = 2 Pi - 10^-6}, WhenEvent[Mod[t, 2 \[Pi]] == 0 && t > number, Sow@t]]` again works 囧 .

Comment: But, not if `number = 2 Pi - 10^-6` is included as a local variable in `Block` instead.

Comment: @bbgodfrey Yeah, and I think the underlying issue is similar: `WhenEvent` only _sees_ the variable `number` rather than the number inside. BTW, I've filed a report with 5 confusing examples just now. If the reply from WRI isn't great, I'll post it as a separate question here.