# Why can't I use logic operator Or to specify multiple events with WhenEvent?

Tags: differential-equations, event-detection

I want to use logic operator `Or` to specify multiple events.

After reading these very helpful posts [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/154539/options-of-whenevent) and [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/39374/inconsistent-behavior-of-whenevent), it seems to be better to use a function to inlude multiple events.

But my code still fails to detect the event.

Although a list of event can be used equivalently in my problem, but I still want the logic operator version.

Thanks!

```
event[x_] := x == 1/2 || x == -(1/4)
sol = NDSolve[
   {x'[t] == -3 x[t], y[t] + x[t] == 1, x[0] == 1, y[0] == 0
    , WhenEvent[event[x[t]], x'[t] -> y'[t]](*fails*)
    (*,WhenEvent[{x[t]\[Equal]1/2,x[t]\[Equal]-1/4},x'[t]\[Rule]y'[
    t]]*)(*works*)
    }, {x[t], y[t]}, {t, 0, 1}, 
   Method -> {"EquationSimplification" -> "Residual"}];

Plot[{x[t], y[t]} /. sol // Evaluate, {t, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> All, 
 PlotLegends -> {"x", "y"}, PlotStyle -> {Blue, {Red, Dashed}}]
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> After reading these very helpful posts [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/154539/1871) and [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/39374/1871), it seems to be better to use a function to inlude multiple events.

This conclusion is definitely wrong. Please notice the posts you've found are about using `And` (`&&`) to construct event, which has its particularity. (If you're interested in this topic, I'd suggest reading [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/211090/1871) together with the comments therein also. )

As to your problem, it's just because the general condition in your code is too hard to satisfy. When a ODE/DAE system is solved by `NDSolve`, function values are only obtained at discretized grid points, so the `x == 1/2 || x == -(1/4)` will almost never be `True`. And defining the condition as a general condition involving `||` will stop `NDSolve` from analyzing the condition. Please read **Details and Options** section of document of `WhenEvent` carefully for more info… OK, let me add an example:

```
func[x_] := x == 1/2
event1 = WhenEvent[func@x[t], "StopIntegration"]
(* WhenEvent[func[x[t]], "StopIntegration"] *)

event2 = WhenEvent[func@x[t] // Evaluate, "StopIntegration"]
(* WhenEvent[x[t] == 1/2, "StopIntegration"] *)

lst = 
  NDSolveValue[{x'[t] == 1, x[0] == 0, #}, x, {t, 0, 1}] & /@ {event1, event2};

ListPlot[#, PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}}] & /@ lst
```

[image]

As we can see, `event1` and `event2` *seem* to be the same, but only `event2` manages to stop the calculation when `x[t] == 1/2`. This is because in `event1`, the condition `x[t] == 1/2` is *hidden* in `func[x[t]]`, so `NDSolve` cannot *see* it. `NDSolve` will then try to handle it in a *general* manner i.e. checking for the point where the `func[x[t]]` becomes `True`: this almost never happen! But `event2` is different, in this case `NDSolve` can *see* the condition is an equation, so it can use root searching technique to find the `t` that satisfies the equation.

"OK, so you mean an `Evaluate` will fix the code?" Sadly it won't help in your case, because **currently only conditions in the first table in Details and Options section of document of `WhenEvent` i.e. `f == 0`, `f > 0`, `f < 0`, `Mod[…] == 0` and `And` are analyzed in special manner by `NDSolve` AFAIK**, so your event involving `Or` (`||`) won't be cleverly analyzed even if we add `Evaluate`.

In my opinion, using a list of event is the way to go here. Why do you want to avoid this? Anyway, if you insist, one work-around is to, as shown in the posts you've found, use inequality to construct a general condition that's easier to satisfy:

```
event[x_] := 0 <= x <= 1/2 || 0 >= x >= -(1/4)

sol = NDSolve[{x'[t] == -3  x[t], y[t] + x[t] == 1, x[0] == 1, y[0] == 0, 
    WhenEvent[event[x[t]], x'[t] -> y'[t]]
    }, {x[t], y[t]}, {t, 0, 1}, Method -> {"EquationSimplification" -> "Residual"}];

Plot[{x[t], y[t]} /. sol // Evaluate, {t, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> All, 
 PlotLegends -> {"x", "y"}, PlotStyle -> {Blue, {Red, Dashed}}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I have to read the software documentation several times almost every time I use the WhenEvent command. I carefully reread the "Details and Options" section, but I didn't find anything new. The article only mentioned cases like f>0 && pred, which is quite understandable, but forgive my dullness, I still can't understand the statement you made, "And defining the condition as a general condition involving || will stop NDSolve from analyzing the condition." Could you please explain this statement in more details? Thank you.

Comment: Yeah, I find your comment on the attribute `HoldAll` of `WhenEvent` in the link you give. It explains a lot. Thanks!

Comment: @xinxin If you find the document too brief, see also the first section of the answer you've found: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/154560/1871 In short, if the event is of special forms listed in document, it'll be analyzed in a cleverer way.

Comment: Thanks. The following conclusion in the post you give is very crucial.
"As an event in WhenEvent[], A && B is not logically equivalent to "A AND B"; rather, it is equivalent to "A IF B."" And Michael E2 suggested hiding the `And` operator using a function.

I would like to ask: What about other logical operators (`Or`, `Not`, etc.)? Do they also pose similar misleading issues?  How to use logical operators to define a general condition for event occurrence?

Comment: @xinxin "Do they also pose similar misleading issues?" No, AFAIK,currently only conditions in the first table in **Details and Options** i.e. `f==0`, `f>0`, `f<0`, `Mod[…]==0` and `And` are analyzed in special manner, other conditions are all treated as general conditions. You can simply consider them as black box functions that output `True` or `False`.

Comment: Thanks! Very helpful!