# WhenEvent not setting discrete variables in If clause

Tags: differential-equations, event-detection

The following example shows two functionally identical versions of the same WhenEvent. The two versions rely on two conditions Condition A and Condition B being satisfied and differ only in the order of the two conditions in the test:

event1: WhenEvent[Condition A && Condition B, actions]

event2: WhenEvent[Condition B && Condition A, actions]

event1 catches the event. event2 does not.  Specifically:

```
event1 = WhenEvent[Evaluate[(toggle[t] == 1) && 
                            (f[S[3][t]][3][t] - f[s[2][t]][2][t] -         
                             f[S[3][t]][2][t] + f[s[2][t]][2][t] < 1/100)],
                   Print[Row[{"End at ", t}]]; Endt = t; "StopIntegration"];

event2 = WhenEvent[Evaluate[(f[S[3][t]][3][t] - f[s[2][t]][2][t] - 
                             f[S[3][t]][2][t] + f[s[2][t]][2][t] < 1/100) &&
                            (toggle[t] == 1)],
                   Print[Row[{"End at ", t}]]; Endt = t; "StopIntegration"];
```

The behavior is not consistent. In some cases, putting the toggle first, fails in others, as here, putting it second fails.

The example relies on an InterpolatingFunctions and requires precision beyond $MachinePrecision

The **variables** are:

```
vars = {s[2], S[3], Cee[3], toggle};
```

with discrete variables:

```
dvars = {toggle};
```

The **initial conditions** are: (sorry, the example relies on precision beyond Machine Precision)

```
initconds = {s[2][
 2.144916158191085905678582630234886355478648729751836407222758673\
1192795799034279814104188519292500682575419414653357410794722550959999\
4740103335481901550805513733884265574044`150.] == 0, 
S[3][2.144916158191085905678582630234886355478648729751836407222758\
6731192795799034279814104188519292500682575419414653357410794722550959\
9994740103335481901550805513733884265574044`150.] == 
0.5141981056084164574889912336386378969597921282604537374345128696\
7276225511023895075588192194971707237837697231024424087411575040786155\
697463394392200504350102087030477646296`150., 
Cee[3][2.\
1449161581910859056785826302348863554786487297518364072227586731192795\
7990342798141041885192925006825754194146533574107947225509599994740103\
335481901550805513733884265574044`150.] == \
-3.7705276082859175241150830989671843407151051321395010246298084465953\
1541552336488269236183953197224497473620271066746924871297392088887135\
59000071618940582406013351697741357`150.72211305893404, 
toggle[2.\
1449161581910859056785826302348863554786487297518364072227586731192795\
7990342798141041885192925006825754194146533574107947225509599994740103\
335481901550805513733884265574044`150.] == 0};
```

The **structural equations** are:

```
eqns = {1/6 + E^(-4 s[2][t]) Derivative[1][Cee[2]][t] - 
              E^(-6 s[2][t]) Derivative[1][Cee[3]][t] - 
       1/6 Derivative[1][s[2]][t] - 
            4 E^(-4 s[2][t]) Cee[2][t] Derivative[1][s[2]][t] + 
            6 E^(-6 s[2][t]) Cee[3][t] Derivative[1][s[2]][t] == 0,

       1/3 + Derivative[1][Cee[3]][t] == 0,

       Derivative[1][S[3]][t] == (1 + 1/3 (-1 + E^(-6 S[3][t])) + 
                                 E^(-2 S[3][t]) Derivative[1][Cee[1]][t]) /
 (2/3 + 2 E^(-2 S[3][t]) Cee[1][t] -  6 E^(-6 S[3][t]) Cee[3][t]) (1 - toggle[t]) + 
 (1/2 + 1/3 (-1 + E^(-6 S[3][t])) + E^(-4 S[3][t]) Derivative[1][Cee[2]][t])/
  (1/6 + 4 E^(-4 S[3][t]) Cee[2][t] - 6 E^(-6 S[3][t]) Cee[3][t])toggle[t]};
```

The values of Cee[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pau7n.png)[t], Cee[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pau7n.png)[t], s[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pau7n.png)[t] and S[2][t] are given by (interpolating) functions ( trimmed these down for simplicity ):

```
Cee[1][t_] := (E^2  (3 - 2 t))/2;

c2points = \
{{1.907617896260767860011475497054036028318446809225144603058751249769\
4806815561571210736776933039564694633481296201461582370798924245736942\
3524758084468476006289788603675904564`150., \
-1.6831025439612610072201840729072758709522572250885761853047264124789\
1694241040816825546302252301433218634695817852766422718211647004164240\
745029965081096221365240085691615911`148.69639563085175}, \
{2.0413599262202311288072004258652563764328000038571304180020184499212\
4962733206272105034877743504054988781268826264296400206168659646195075\
76239092536031285484207595334058418`150., \
-2.9802757705333724103451089062908125112436423335851539685538595957120\
2338717379906886248580943245246548769431104777619881113407633292773814\
612688264309365198046850807694808338`150.}, \
{2.1394604850920685589650768423895210777029979995549773439374302764608\
0056809835998881873742408196150766674393824047905104371427542515405132\
966977252364434006623176591046317048`150., \
-4.1290963519258740800612276198173942460010650856221724269232975381140\
4900572369657119634822748960849090051135145287106739101240762847312401\
951640176423245809950065109807886723`150.}, \
{2.1433148556815212671537742657567336649611712343085516174662774029292\
7460921208246166328403525510432875056666575741050789208701128187287638\
520397966617725098222519176200496852`150., \
-4.1773462467078870788521151457077965227474892220344787423604223110122\
2726494814089345409587051196090635066927105048223158578001067150156773\
688524331255056708978911047703185954`150.}, \
{2.1449020728573698382827764277176392396912721240247133546700032241770\
6876700338027284581284655739244983125293596229770212201148191454691173\
642596838659032585171623606134361551`150., \
-4.1972810022299009595088425923374635051700681629514865849548865245995\
9246305764261381958227988898592942518117173506455750283004345251488660\
317405946505439657136177859108646252`150.}, \
{2.1524976456510253553962129239426156378722267983024141518610312867259\
7452105861449613310586508219833000268794054716280380487156080986214508\
113456303415163509006374736040187426`150., \
-4.2012488228255126776981064619713078189361133991512070759305156433629\
8726052930724806655293254109916500134397027358140190243578040493107254\
056728151707581754503187368028951726`150.}, \
{2.1704528697691028131628080771602455975585625465337067996509753587849\
0582284287752664906109596552119666892247042888895590631488377717233411\
383140967127700376963250532987180038`150., \
-4.2102264348845514065814040385801227987792812732668533998254876793924\
5291142143876332453054798276059833446123521444447795315744188858616705\
69157048356385018848162526650020244`150.}, \
{2.1997385373007056885504600897448336068263923196982653614879777587903\
7527453125485508254295651193074534301956318153762896616668903160238654\
423316201040305376342962332116725601`150., \
-4.2248692686503528442752300448724168034131961598491326807439888793951\
8763726562742754127147825596537267150978159076881448308334451580119327\
211658100520152688171481166059616834`150.}, \
{2.2426677524724705445204419922936684446643779334834943318368757760847\
7341792656130123831289308271205103044971736676542624140572644717873036\
922204315569577969701784100632101874`150., \
-4.2463338762362352722602209961468342223321889667417471659184378880423\
8670896328065061915644654135602551522485868338271312070286322358936518\
461102157784788984850892050316050932`150.}, \
{2.2772837446481053037681387264688332430308241721896523291778067433461\
6942613300774020831581745654555806249277125056899052504484167960112328\
376380723793629828293879072055725864`150., \
-4.2636418723240526518840693632344166215154120860948261645889033716730\
8471306650387010415790872827277903124638562528449526252242083980056164\
188190361896814914146939536027862927`150.}, \
{2.2825727937800136574760942092141594475729150546101098966785798733491\
8875391625084559228420170724077132249695456997820494325046387000946429\
985522474100794875187322697576350482`150., \
-4.2662863968900068287380471046070797237864575273050549483392899366745\
9437695812542279614210085362038566124847728498910247162523193500473214\
992761237050397437593661348788175241`150.}};
Cee[2] = Interpolation[c2points];

s1points = \
{{1.907617896260767860011475497054036028318446809225144603058751249769\
4806815561571210736776933039564694633481296201461582370798924245736942\
3524758084468476006289788603675904564`150., 
2.0552220905714129556973373980828549801740262538921295191524341804\
9357017940349356907852781700252741951426269368691848649449318994193148\
135437153310684034`128.62020399867365*^-21}, \
{2.0413599262202311288072004258652563764328000038571304180020184499212\
4962733206272105034877743504054988781268826264296400206168659646195075\
76239092536031285484207595334058418`150., 
0.1438911828442204935725243878882738952493618527856549839220804593\
5625748917823332280795156471990694299579743967873377464043981372658187\
524781886978853732783626102783057079565`150.}, \
{2.1394604850920685589650768423895210777029979995549773439374302764608\
0056809835998881873742408196150766674393824047905104371427542515405132\
966977252364434006623176591046317048`150., 
0.2234978924877639547733243542118064814045564346472745970093807492\
3106902407513938078883672651374541881865391290691918123330278702259751\
423488704780286016712273654093855760828`150.}, \
{2.1433148556815212671537742657567336649611712343085516174662774029292\
7460921208246166328403525510432875056666575741050789208701128187287638\
520397966617725098222519176200496852`150., 
0.2262938229965847979922893729604833117843691848353531586328403386\
0486328621807791334911808768322184596347570247516659382434374484076681\
633773206568249700412229013808699810722`150.}, \
{2.1449020728573698382827764277176392396912721240247133546700032241770\
6876700338027284581284655739244983125293596229770212201148191454691173\
642596838659032585171623606134361551`150., 
0.2274386983268234349722641495898086400088320534399941587258955730\
5406110760801461717549401883533381074453413492879710513146814248351680\
41226531551182106648792918210844384504`150.}, \
{2.1524976456510253553962129239426156378722267983024141518610312867259\
7452105861449613310586508219833000268794054716280380487156080986214508\
113456303415163509006374736040187426`150., 
0.2046194556266479114894462269693918112977027039898001156890038526\
2565704565770804156414009373920895948170755267352449123979716471628646\
757660551036602908857693542011191711511`150.}, \
{2.1704528697691028131628080771602455975585625465337067996509753587849\
0582284287752664906109596552119666892247042888895590631488377717233411\
383140967127700376963250532987180038`150., 
0.1613330783228310701053250413789435602236932564847625997844096722\
8734393416493934926628151042712058371531306154120554045894457390890492\
011488656451096244233403803609571098293`150.}, \
{2.1997385373007056885504600897448336068263923196982653614879777587903\
7527453125485508254295651193074534301956318153762896616668903160238654\
423316201040305376342962332116725601`150., 
0.1072742122004427274716358126528535424620851032575048041371412699\
6926598049700959551847229520969989786682939626764366707779527657393690\
074470140594612486017532911281477680022`150.}, \
{2.2426677524724705445204419922936684446643779334834943318368757760847\
7341792656130123831289308271205103044971736676542624140572644717873036\
922204315569577969701784100632101874`150., 
0.0461581812070294184757151282685988408076323405225660223909810006\
8259742850683984420496093581369244617360175653055392146635436195290941\
716705040628010198357611733708446053393`150.}, \
{2.2772837446481053037681387264688332430308241721896523291778067433461\
6942613300774020831581745654555806249277125056899052504484167960112328\
376380723793629828293879072055725864`150., 
0.0057055457060056295448370160812683374085937984973857263036062713\
4059080640127104859541121073382728776777258674316217064121230695841395\
818832069770391596715596071342029335437`150.}, \
{2.2825727937800136574760942092141594475729150546101098966785798733491\
8875391625084559228420170724077132249695456997820494325046387000946429\
985522474100794875187322697576350482`150., 
0.0000164205526152212166032480779119018332708249265010096431085712\
5736237769346524344259994646299987529478525153698171936862785409026397\
3395186010914832598911887191079997827526871447302897069324`150.}};
s[1] = Interpolation[s1points];

S2points = \
{{1.907617896260767860011475497054036028318446809225144603058751249769\
4806815561571210736776933039564694633481296201461582370798924245736942\
3524758084468476006289788603675904564`150., 
0.2555972772662321381648526908078933136183388957477167001636844734\
8106055126214072298836985577295125918675149302587323259236044938508514\
08136012742005788664176488519436371095`148.6888889906263}, \
{2.0413599262202311288072004258652563764328000038571304180020184499212\
4962733206272105034877743504054988781268826264296400206168659646195075\
76239092536031285484207595334058418`150., 
0.3999868938550802741951986141677280118318714064484576040266690718\
5426342229089866502111739344909276314161774503913459055657635665039189\
236127563582095935477123023992146439785`150.}, \
{2.1394604850920685589650768423895210777029979995549773439374302764608\
0056809835998881873742408196150766674393824047905104371427542515405132\
966977252364434006623176591046317048`150., 
0.4786883136209545792859937066712261354487123832746058194147770848\
9476802055809089568124582464557017161429451151946658066813533189216531\
161719436988864538022072595642290059281`150.}, \
{2.1433148556815212671537742657567336649611712343085516174662774029292\
7460921208246166328403525510432875056666575741050789208701128187287638\
520397966617725098222519176200496852`150., 
0.4814328302943097155888637601093749856568653260556738826950734954\
1428100138210863079268986240945507210792842670431641423429828289097095\
435224906310845297605899884630887554937`150.}, \
{2.1449020728573698382827764277176392396912721240247133546700032241770\
6876700338027284581284655739244983125293596229770212201148191454691173\
642596838659032585171623606134361551`150., 
0.4825562314583134967424318439985141484171820541242716736730865677\
4775559791157070311649761481292739413011096464080394070060557858837201\
550684616671990166917913854807197380287`150.}, \
{2.1524976456510253553962129239426156378722267983024141518610312867259\
7452105861449613310586508219833000268794054716280380487156080986214508\
113456303415163509006374736040187426`150., 
0.5049446981665887677211361351007665672082848309076926933805753238\
0844959149718694228670770833245587891243111649979967964839562076167648\
703690230083593851202554304237309283617`150.}, \
{2.1704528697691028131628080771602455975585625465337067996509753587849\
0582284287752664906109596552119666892247042888895590631488377717233411\
383140967127700376963250532987180038`150., 
0.5471155211735693496040709470801262540842240615192902139672243256\
2667020191603502168031800239131106228156059140677344800835317639098258\
510839323365008647966856963668557884889`150.}, \
{2.1997385373007056885504600897448336068263923196982653614879777587903\
7527453125485508254295651193074534301956318153762896616668903160238654\
423316201040305376342962332116725601`150., 
0.5992196256999047609374999588954923738405068718024291297459980081\
9872182816586916310037570042577026988538056540954459830320780335184626\
701872248236090193240415654537092937973`150.}, \
{2.2426677524724705445204419922936684446643779334834943318368757760847\
7341792656130123831289308271205103044971736676542624140572644717873036\
922204315569577969701784100632101874`150., 
0.6571975539248695315054172282033106166532344527205321922749750742\
2786060606343431743664022280579770911400633855278635579856002294580584\
273623182129252075459227931295787830937`150.}, \
{2.2772837446481053037681387264688332430308241721896523291778067433461\
6942613300774020831581745654555806249277125056899052504484167960112328\
376380723793629828293879072055725864`150., 
0.6949121779118717653475440036590601284112194802917932849675618170\
4633427302282746532760537267282667430336368821047010698945410350813400\
592488862761056162417239350916136729806`150.}, \
{2.2825727937800136574760942092141594475729150546101098966785798733491\
8875391625084559228420170724077132249695456997820494325046387000946429\
985522474100794875187322697576350482`150., 
0.7001682321237943327529007467937328937872073090037677451471472609\
5449029110817622825435024260497168894490291415805249103115677923448857\
534581655219099259204098776288774974834`150.}};
S[2] = Interpolation[S2points];
```

The Event trigger is defined by :

f[S[3][t]][3][t]- f[s[2][t]][3][t] - f[S[3][t]][2][t] + f[s[2][t]][2][t] < 1/100 when toggle[3][2] == 1, where

```
f[x_][i_][t_] := x +  x /(2 i^2) - x^2/(2 i) + (x t)/i - (E^(-2 x i)  Cee[i][t])/(2 i);
```

There are two flavors of events:

toggle events trigger a change in the discrete variable toggle[t]

```
toggleevent = WhenEvent[Evaluate[(S[3][t] < S[2][t])], {Print[Row[{"toggle event at ", t}]], toggle[t] -> 1, "RemoveEvent"}];
```

The event triggered by f can be written testing the toggle first or testing the toggle second:

```
event1 = WhenEvent[Evaluate[(toggle[t] ==1) && 
                            (f[S[3][t]][3][t] - f[s[2][t]][2][t] - f[S[3][t]][2][t] + f[s[2][t]][2][t] < 1/100)],
         Print[Row[{"End at ", t}]]; Endt = t; "StopIntegration"];

event2 = WhenEvent[Evaluate[(f[S[3][t]][3][t] - f[s[2][t]][2][t] - f[S[3][t]][2][t] + f[s[2][t]][2][t] < 1/100) && 
                            (toggle[t] == 1)],
         Print[Row[{"End at ", t}]]; Endt = t; "StopIntegration"];
```

**Testing the toggle first**

```
Dynamic[dynreport]

startt = 2.14491615819108590567858263023488635547864872975183640722275867311927957990342798141041885192925006825754194146533574107947225509599994740103335481901550805513733884265574044`150.;
Print[f[S[3][t]][3][t] - f[s[2][t]][3][t] - f[S[3][t]][2][t] + f[s[2][t]][2][t] /.t -> startt /. (initconds /. Equal -> Rule)]; 
sol1 = First[NDSolve[Join[eqns, initconds, {toggleevent, event1}], vars,       
                     {t, -\[Infinity], startt}, DiscreteVariables ->dvars,
                     EvaluationMonitor :> {Pause[0.005];
                     dynreport = Column[{Row[{"Stop Criterion = ", Style[f[S[3][t]][3][t] - f[s[2][t]][3][t] - f[S[3][t]][2][t] + f[s[2][t]][2][t], 
                      If[f[S[3][t]][3][t] - f[s[2][t]][2][t] - f[S[3][t]][2][t] + f[s[2][t]][2][t] < 1/100, Red, Black]]}], 
                                         Row[{"t = ", t}],
                                         Row[{"s[2] = ", s[2][t]}],                                        
                                         Row[{"S[3] = ", Style[S[3][t], If[S[3][t] <= S[2][t], Green, Black]]}],                                      
                                         Row[{"C[3] = ", Cee[3][t]}],                                    
                                         Row[{"toggle = ", toggle[t]}]
                                      }]}]];
Print[f[S[3][t]][3][t] - f[s[2][t]][3][t] - f[S[3][t]][2][t] + f[s[2][t]][2][t] /. sol1 /. t -> Endt];
```

This yields roughly the expected result:

(Output)

```
   0.1180039500392493987880273545540440553287906640253476084874518519607305453545644587291707233055968411834327367482888605333490514238621090923567733881

toggle event at 2.09444

End at 2.09444

0.0212756
```

The precision of the event location is pretty poor (probably due to the trimmed InterpolatingFunctions), but it did capture the event.

**Testing the toggle second** does not work:

```
Endt = -\[Infinity]; startt =2.14491615819108590567858263023488635547864872975183640722275867311927957990342798141041885192925006825754194146533574107947225509599994740103335481901550805513733884265574044`150.;
Print[f[S[3][t]][3][t] - f[s[2][t]][3][t] - f[S[3][t]][2][t] + f[s[2][t]][2][t] /.t -> startt /. (initconds /. Equal -> Rule)]; 
sol2 = First[NDSolve[Join[eqns, initconds, {toggleevent, event2}], vars,       
                     {t, -\[Infinity], startt}, DiscreteVariables ->dvars,
             EvaluationMonitor :> {Pause[0.005];
             dynreport2 = 
                       Column[{Row[{"Stop Criterion = ", Style[f[S[3][t]][3][t] - f[s[2][t]][3][t] - f[S[3][t]][2][t] + f[s[2][t]][2][t], 
                             If[f[S[3][t]][3][t] - f[s[2][t]][2][t] - f[S[3][t]][2][t] +f[s[2][t]][2][t] < 1/100, Red, Black]]}], 
                              Row[{"t = ", t}],
                              Row[{"s[2] = ", s[2][t]}],
                              Row[{"S[3] = ", Style[S[3][t], If[S[3][t] <= S[2][t], Green, Black]]}],
                              Row[{"C[3] = ", Cee[3][t]}],
                              Row[{"toggle = ", toggle[t]}]
                                      }]}]];
Print[Endt];
```

That yields

(Output)

```
0.1180039500392493987880273545540440553287906640253476084874518519607305453545644587291707233055968411834327367482888605333490514238621090923567733881

toggle event at 2.09444

NDSolve::ndsz: At t == 2.0667528920546507`, step size is effectively zero; singularity or stiff system suspected. >>

-\[Infinity]
```

event2 did not catch a point at which toggle[t]==1 and the function value was less than 1

A plot of the toggle value, the f test value and the cut off

```
Plot[{f[S[3][t]][3][t] - f[s[2][t]][3][t] - f[S[3][t]][2][t] + f[s[2][t]][2][t] /. sol2 /. t -> time, 
      toggle[t] /. sol2 /. t -> time, 1/100}, 
    {time, 2.06676, startt}, 
   PlotLegends -> {"f trigger value", "toggle value", "f trigger target"}]
```

[image]

Comment: `Dt` is an internal, `Protected` symbol.  I cannot set it to a value at all.

Comment: Your 2nd `WhenEvent` is incomplete. it has an odd number of `[` brackets.

Comment: A strict reading of the syntax in the docs suggests that multiple actions need separate codes: `WhenEvent[<event>, <single action code>]` or `WhenEvent[< event>, {<single action>, <single action>,...}]`. What you have is not a list of codes, but a single code that evaluates to a list of actions. The problem has nothing to do specifically with `If[]`: even, `Null; {Dt = t, Dtoggle[t] -> 1, "RemoveEvent"}` fails. I guess you would need to repeat the `If[]` test for each action.

Comment: Related: The difference in switching the event and condition in `WhenEvent[event && condition, action]` is discussed [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/39374/inconsistent-behavior-of-whenevent)

Comment: Note that `WhenEvent[expr < 1/100 && condition, action]` triggers an event only when the value of `expr` changes from greater than `1/100` to less than `1/100`.   Your `f` trigger value does not do that in the last plot.  Perhaps `WhenEvent[expr == 1/100 && condition, action]` is what you're after.