# How to increase the speed of NDsolve when using WhenEvent

Tags: differential-equations, event-detection

I am trying to solve a set of ODE's with switching. I implemented using `WhenEvents`.

```
xd = {1/√6, √5/√6};
x0 = {1/√2, 1/√2};
min = -0.0001;
max = 0.0001;
tmax = 10;
sol = NDSolve[{
   x1'[t] == -x2[t]*u1[t],
   x2'[t] == x1[t]*u1[t],
   WhenEvent[xd[[1]]* x2[t] - xd[[2]] x1[t] > max, u1[t] -> -1],
   WhenEvent[xd[[1]]* x2[t] - xd[[2]] x1[t] < min, u1[t] -> 1],
   x1[0] == x0[[1]], x2[0] == x0[[2]], u1[0] == -1},
  {x1, x2, x3, u1}, {t, 0, tmax}, DiscreteVariables -> {u1}]
Plot[{xd[[1]], xd[[2]], x1[t] /. sol, x2[t] /. sol}, {t, 0, tmax}, 
 PlotPoints -> 10000]
Plot[u1[t] /. sol, {t, 0, tmax}, PlotPoints -> 10000]
```

[image: It performs as intended!]

How ever, I need to another event `WhenEvent[ xd[[1]]* x2[t] - xd[[2]] x1[t] < max &&  xd[[1]]* x2[t] - xd[[2]] x1[t] > min, u1[t] -> 0]`, it takes hours and does not produce results.

I think, the last event is raising too many events, so it's taking a lot of time. Is there a work around for this?

Comment: I think it's just the new event; try it as the only event.  Possibly related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/39393/4999

Comment: Perhaps `WhenEvent[Null; <ineq.>, u1[t] -> 0]` from my answer in the link does what you want?

Comment: @MichaelE2 No, it did not work. For `f(x)>eps`, `f(x)<-eps` it works. I want to include the event `-eps<f(x)<eps`.

Comment: @MichaelE2 I checked it. I think it's not related to my issue.

Comment: Thanks for the accept!  This might be worth reporting to Wolfram.  I might not be considered a bug, but I think they would want the behavior to be a bit better here.  I suspect the algorithm could be improved.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Thanks for the Help. Yeah, maybe we can submit this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems to be related to the event location method.  I used `foo` to indicate when an event was detected, and `murf` to show when a step is taken.  With the default `"LocationMethod"`, the integration gets stuck on the first event.  This happens even when the other two events are removed.  It also happens only if the event action is `u[t] -> 0`; change it to another nonzero value, and everything works fine.  (I guess this makes sense.  `NDSolve` is trying to find where the event occurs, but each time it steps across the event, the system stops moving, since `u[t] == 0` sets all derivatives equal to zero.  I guess that's confusing the root-finding algorithm.)

```
foo = murf = 0.;
PrintTemporary@
  Dynamic@{foo, Style[murf, PrintPrecision -> 17], Clock@Infinity};
xd = {1/√6, √5/√6};
x0 = {1/√2, 1/√2};
min = -0.0001;
max = 0.0001;
tmax = 10;
sol = NDSolve[{x1'[t] == -x2[t]*u1[t], x2'[t] == x1[t]*u1[t],
   WhenEvent[
    xd[[1]]*x2[t] - xd[[2]] x1[t] > min && 
     xd[[1]]*x2[t] - xd[[2]] x1[t] < max,
    foo = t; u1[t] -> 0, "LocationMethod" -> "LinearInterpolation"],
   WhenEvent[xd[[1]]*x2[t] - xd[[2]] x1[t] > max,(*foo=t;*)
    u1[t] -> -1],
   WhenEvent[xd[[1]]*x2[t] - xd[[2]] x1[t] < min,(*foo=t;*)u1[t] -> 1],
   x1[0] == x0[[1]], x2[0] == x0[[2]], u1[0] == -1},
  {x1, x2, x3, u1}, {t, 0, tmax}, 
  DiscreteVariables -> {u1 ∈ {-1, 0, 1}}, 
  StepMonitor :> (murf = t), MaxSteps -> 1000]
```

Of course it's stops pretty soon:

```
Plot[{xd[[1]], xd[[2]], x1[t] /. sol, x2[t] /. sol}, {t, 0, tmax}]
Plot[u1[t] /. sol, {t, 0, tmax}, PlotPoints -> 100]
```

[image]